# Vector angle with a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry

I have a vector $A=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$.

Now I want to find the angle made by the vector with the planes $XY$, $YZ$, $ZX$.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

The angle $\theta$ between two vectors $\bf u$ and $\bf v$ is defined using the dot product: $$\cos\theta = \frac{\bf u \cdot v}{\bf \lVert u\rVert \lVert v\rVert}$$

To find the angle between a vector $\bf u$ and a plane, first find the angle between $\bf u$ and the normal to the plane, then subtract it from $\pi / 2$.

Comment: Actually, I have only information about $u$ (= $A$). Is there any way to find out $v$...only knowing $u$?

Comment: @Bikash In your case, you have information about the planes also: the normal vector to the $x,y$-plane is $[0,0,1]$, for example.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!!